# Airflow: Debugging Python in DockerOperator

Tags: python, docker, airflow, dockeroperator

Is there a way to debug Python interactively in `pdb` or `ipdb` when executed with the [DockerOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html)?

What I've tried so far:

```py
import datetime as dt

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker import DockerOperator

with DAG(
    dag_id='dag_test_with_docker',
    start_date=dt.datetime(2022, 1, 1),
) as dag:
    
    t1 = DockerOperator(
        task_id='do_some_etl',
        image='python:3.11',
        tty=True,
        command='python -c "import pdb, time; pdb.set_trace(); time.sleep(2)"',
    )
    t1
```

Then executing a `airflow tasks test` with:

```bash
airflow tasks test dag_test_with_docker do_some_etl 2023-01-01
```

What I get:

```bash
[2024-02-02T13:36:59.752+0100] {docker.py:429} INFO - --Return--
> <string>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb)
```

When trying the same with `ipdb` (other docker image), then I get the following error message:

```bash
[2024-02-02T13:16:46.116+0100] {docker.py:429} WARNING: your terminal doesn't support cursor position requests (CPR).
```

My problem is, that this pdb session is not interactive. I cannot send any ipdb/pdb commands back.
Is there a solution for this, to allow debugging of the python code executed in the Docker container via DockerOperator?

Environment:

```
Apache Airflow 2.7.3
Docker Engine - Community, Version 24.0.7
```